# How is single nucleotide polymorphism denoted?

Tags: biochemistry, dna, mutations, snp

Currently I'm studying an article on [TERT promoter mutations in human melanoma](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23348506) and find myself unfamiliar with included denotations,I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me what **C228T** in the sentence below means.

> Two tumors with a C228T transition also contained an adjacent C>T transition (at position chr5,
>   1,295,229), which is indicative of a dinucleotide CC>TT transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C228T is a mutation from Citosin to Thymin at the 228th basepair.

Maybe this website helps? [Nomenclature for the description of mutations and other sequence variations](http://atlasgeneticsoncology.org/Educ/NomMutID30067ES.html)
I see they write the mutation different (following their format it would be 228C>T), but the general idea is the same.